# Facebook Sharer doesn't show all images for selection

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I've got some image on our site where I included the Open Graph tag `og:image`.

For example the main company logo has such a tag as it should always be selectable and then there are some article pages or news and the lead image of those pages also has also the `og:image` tag.

When I test it using the sharer button on our page or browserbar-button (or any other way) the share dialog does only show me the image of the article page and not the company logo for selection.

You can test it here:
http://www.up-great.ch/unsere-firma/wegbeschreibung

Funny thing is, that if I use the Facebook Debugger Tool the images (2 images) are all there:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.up-great.ch%2Funsere-firma%2Fwegbeschreibung

Why is there a difference between the debug tool and the share dialog? (Btw, I know that I don't use `og:url` tag but I once added it to the page and there was no difference even after resetting the Cache with the FB debugger).

FB sharer bug oder am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One year later still no answer.

I just tried the same and it doesn't work neither in your nor in my testcase: http://mattweb.de/open-graph-multiple-images/

To me it seems Facebook changed this to one image only, but it's not documented anywhere.

I remember once it worked (even without Open Graph tags) but couldn't tell when that was. Now I know that it must have been more than a year. So thanks for your question.

Regards,
Matt